# After updating user detail, the page gets blank and I have to reload browser to display the page with updated data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, tailwind-css

When I'm trying to update user details through a modal, the page where user details are gets blank. I have to reload the browser to load the user page.

User.js ->

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import noteContext from '../context/notes/noteContext';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Useritem from './Useritem';


const User = (props) => {

    const context = useContext(noteContext);
    const { fetchUser, editUser, deleteUser } = context;
    const { showalert } = props;
    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false)
    const [check, setCheck] = useState(false)
    const [deletemodal, setDeletemodal] = useState(false)
    const [delete_user, setDeleteuser] = useState({ id: "" })
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
            fetchUser();
        }
        else {
            showalert("Login to see your details", "danger");
            navigate('/login')
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [])

    const [newUser, setNewuser] = useState({ id: "", username: "", lastname: "", age: "", email: "", password: "", change_password: "" })

    const updateNote = (currentUser) => {
        setModal(true);
        setNewuser({ id: currentUser._id, username: currentUser.name, lastname: currentUser.lastname, age: currentUser.age, email: currentUser.email, password: "", change_password: "" })
    }

    const deleteConfirm = (user_id) => {
        setDeletemodal(true)
        setDeleteuser({ id: user_id })
    }

    const handleDelete = (e) => {
        deleteUser(delete_user.id);
        setDeletemodal(false);
        navigate('/login');
    }

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        editUser(newUser.id, newUser.username, newUser.lastname, newUser.age, newUser.password, newUser.change_password);
        window.location.reload(); //I had to use this so that when i click on update the page get reload
    }
    const onChange = (e) => {
        setNewuser({ ...newUser, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }


    return (
        <div>
            {/* Update user Modal */}
            <div className={`${modal ? '' : 'hidden'} relative z-10`} aria-labelledby="modal-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">



                <div className="bg-white px-4 pb-4 pt-5 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                    <div className="">
                        <div className="mx-auto flex h-12 w-auto justify-between   sm:mx-0 sm:h-10 ">
                            <button onClick={() => setModal(!modal)} >X</button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="mt-3 text-center sm:ml-4 sm:mt-0 sm:text-left">
                            <h3 className="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900" id="modal-title">Update your details {newUser.id}</h3>
                            <div className="mt-2">
                                <form>

                                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value={newUser.username} onChange={onChange} minLength={5} required />
                                    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" value={newUser.lastname} onChange={onChange} minLength={5} required />
                                    <input type="number" id="age" name="age" value={newUser.age} onChange={onChange} minLength={5} required />
                                    <input disabled type="text" id="email" name="email" value={newUser.email} onChange={onChange} minLength={5} required />
                                    <input onClick={() => setCheck(!check)} type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" />
                                    <input disabled={check ? false : true} type="text" id="password" name="password" value={newUser.password} onChange={onChange} />
                                    <input disabled={check ? false : true} type="text" id="change_password" name="change_password" value={newUser.change_password} onChange={onChange} />
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse sm:px-6">
                    <button onClick={handleClick} type="button" >Update</button>
                    <button onClick={() => setModal(!modal)} type="button" >Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            {/* End of Update user Modal */}

            {/* Delete user modal */}
            <div className={`${deletemodal ? '' : 'hidden'} relative z-10`} aria-labelledby="modal-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">

                <div >
                    <div className="bg-white px-4 pb-4 pt-5 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                        <div className="">
                            <div className="mx-auto flex h-12 w-auto justify-between   sm:mx-0 sm:h-10 ">
                                <button onClick={() => setDeletemodal(!deletemodal)} >X</button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="mt-3 text-center sm:ml-4 sm:mt-0 sm:text-left">
                                <h3 className="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900" id="modal-title">Are you sure you want to delete your account?</h3>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse sm:px-6">
                        <button onClick={handleDelete} type="button" >Delete</button>
                        <button onClick={() => setDeletemodal(!deletemodal)} type="button" >Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {/* End of Delete user Modal */}

            <div>
                <Useritem updateNote={updateNote} deleteConfirm={deleteConfirm} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default User
```

UserItem.js ->

```
import React,{useEffect, useContext} from 'react'
import noteContext from '../context/notes/noteContext';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";



const Useritem = (props) => {

    const { updateNote, deleteConfirm } = props;
    const context = useContext(noteContext);
    const { userdetail } = context;

    let navigate = useNavigate();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!localStorage.getItem("token")) {
            navigate('/login');
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [])
    
    const userData = userdetail.user;
  
    return (
        <div>
            {/* ----------------- user page ------------ */}

            {userData && <div className="p-16">
                <div className="p-8 bg-white shadow mt-24">
                    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3">
                        <div className="grid grid-cols-3 text-center order-last md:order-first mt-20 md:mt-0">
                            <div>
                                <p className="font-bold text-gray-700 text-xl">{detail.countNotes}</p>
                                <p className="text-gray-400">Total Notes</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p className="font-bold text-gray-700 text-xl">{userData._id}</p>
                                <p className="text-gray-400">ID</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="space-x-8 flex justify-between mt-32 md:mt-0 md:justify-center">
                            <button onClick={() => { updateNote(userData) }}>
                                Edit
                            </button>
                            <button onClick={() => { deleteConfirm(userData._id) }} >
                                Deactivate
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="mt-20 text-center border-b pb-12">
                        <h1 className="text-4xl font-medium text-gray-700">
                            {userData.name}, <span className="font-light text-gray-500">{userData.age}</span>
                        </h1>
                        <p className="font-light text-gray-600 mt-3">{userData.lastname}, {userData.name}</p>
                        <p className="mt-8 text-gray-500">
                            Email - {userData.email}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Useritem
```

NoteState.js ->

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import NoteContext from "./noteContext"; 

const NoteState = (props) => {

    const host = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000';
   
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    
    const [userdetail, setUserdetail] = useState('')

    //Fetch User
    const fetchUser = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/auth/getuser`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "auth-token": authToken
            },
        });
        const json = await response.json(); 
        setUserdetail(json);
    }

    // Update user
    const editUser = async (id, name, lastname, age, password, newPassword) => {
        //API call
        const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/auth/updateuser/${id}`, {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "auth-token": authToken
            },

            body: JSON.stringify({ name, lastname, age, password, newPassword }), 
        });
        const json = await response.json();
        console.log(json)

        let updatedUser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userdetail))
       
        console.log(updatedUser);

        if (updatedUser._id === id) {
            updatedUser.name = name;
            updatedUser.lastname = lastname;
            updatedUser.age = age;
            updatedUser.password = newPassword;
            
        }

        console.log(updatedUser);

        if (json.success) {
            props.showalert(`${json.message}`, 'success');
            console.log(json.message)
        } else {
            if (json.message === undefined) {
                props.showalert(`Oops unable to update your details`, 'danger');
                console.log(json.message + 'Unable to update your details')
            } else {
                props.showalert(`${json.message}`, 'danger');
                console.log(json.message)
            }
        }
        setUserdetail(updatedUser)
    }


    return (
       
        <NoteContext.Provider value={{ fetchUser, userdetail, editUser, deleteUser }}>
            {props.children}
        </NoteContext.Provider>
    )
}


export default NoteState;
```

NoteContext.js ->

```
import { createContext } from "react";
const noteContext = createContext();
export default noteContext;
```

App.js ->

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import NoteState from "./context/notes/NoteState";
import './App.css';
import Alerts from "./components/Alerts";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Singup from "./components/Singup";
import { useState } from "react";
import User from "./components/User";


// TODO use context API for ALERT

function App() {

  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(null);

  const showalert = (message, type) => {
    setAlert({
      msg: message,
      type: type
    })
    setTimeout(()=>{
      setAlert(null);
    },2000)
  }

  return (
    <NoteState showalert={showalert}>
      <BrowserRouter>

        <Navbar showalert={showalert}/>
        <div className="">
        <Alerts alert={alert} />
          <Routes>

            <Route exact path='/' element={<Home showalert={showalert} />} />
            <Route exact path='/login' element={<Login showalert={showalert}/>} />
            <Route exact path='/singup' element={<Singup showalert={showalert}/>} />
            <Route exact path='/user' element={<User showalert={showalert}/>} />

          </Routes>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </NoteState>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have updated my code a little bit from reading comments. Now the page doesnt vanish. But to display the updated data i have to reload the page.

Below are the snip of what's happing ->

[Initial image of user page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5cCy.png)

[Updating details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUmL6.png)

[After click update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyGx6.png)

[After reloading page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPMbq.png)

I'm also displaying message from the function where logs are coming from. Hope it helps
[Console log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXODt.png)

[image after updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMwAU.png)

Comment: Can you please check and add the console logs?

Comment: Where are you using `NoteState`?

Comment: where is `notes` defined?

Comment: Hey guys, I have updated my question with console logs as you asked. Hope it helps.

And you guys can ignore **notes** part, that's another  component. If you want then i can paste them too.

Comment: @PrashantRao I updated my answer after reviewing the logs

Comment: Add the `newUser` dependency in `useEffect` your problem every time you update use the `newUser` state values also updating then just make reload the component then so it shows the `updatedUserData`

Comment: @PrashantRao please follow the above comment i did then check and tell me if you still see the problem I cannot post this as a answer because I just answer another question so StackOverflow not allowing me to that

Comment: I have update my code a little bit. Now the page dosent vanish. But to display updated data i have to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your types are off.

- `UserItem` expects `userDetail` from the context to be an object (with `user` and `countNotes` properties). So this must also be the type returned by the GET endpoint.
- After PUT request we write `notes`/`updatedUser` to `userDetail` which is assumed to be an array according to the code.

After reviewing the logs, I believe the error is that `UserItem` gets passed an array as `detail` which means `userData = detail.user // == undefined` and hence the `UserItem` component won't render. Since we have `{userData &&`.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I have update my code a little bit. Now the page dosent vanish. But to display updated data i have to reload the page. I have tried what you pointed to be off types. Kindly review it. and let me know whats need to be updated now.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `newUser` dependency in `useEffect` your problem every time you update use the `newUser` state values also updating then just make reload the component then so it shows the `updatedUserData`

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
            fetchUser();
        }
        else {
            showalert("Login to see your details", "danger");
            navigate('/login')
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [newUser])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks all for your suggestion, I noticed what was wrong in my code.

My state was not getting updated in NoteState.js in edit(), So i did this ->

`

```
let updatedUser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json))
updatedUser = updatedUser.user;
if (updatedUser._id === id) {

    let newupdatedUser = {
        ...userdetail,
        user: {
            ...userdetail.user,
            name: updatedUser.name,
            lastname: updatedUser.lastname,
            age: updatedUser.age
        }
    };

    setUserdetail(newupdatedUser);
}
```

`

Its working now. Also please let me know if its the correct way to update the state.